# How to group select images

Tags: delphi, transparent

My application has a panel (TRzPanel) that can contain many icons (TAdvShape). Each icon can be dragged and dropped. My user can also select multiple icons and move them in mass with keystrokes.

I want to select icons with a transparent 'frame' that can select and move icons as it's done on the IDE.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That *transparent 'frame'* is called a *selection rectangle*. Perhaps if you look for that in your favorite search engine?

Comment: Yes it did help. I just need the name for the function I was looking for.
I used the AI search in Edge. Chrome didn't do that good of a job.